# How to use a thread in a context manager?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, contextmanager

Consider this `threading.Thread` class:

```
class Sleeper(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, sleep=5.0):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.event = threading.Event()
        self.sleep = sleep

    def run(self):
        while self.sleep > 0 and not self.event.is_set():
            self.event.wait(1.0)
            self.sleep -= 1

    def stop(self):
        self.event.set()
```

It sleeps for a certain amount of time and exits or is stopped before reaching that amount.

I use it as:

```
sleeper = Sleeper()
try:
    sleeper.start()
    # do stuffs here
except:
    # handle possible exceptions here
finally:
    sleeper.stop()
```

And I would much rather use it like a context manager:

```
with Sleeper():
    # do stuffs here
```

and then the thread is stopped when exiting the `with` block.

I have tried adding `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods and it seems to work but I'm not sure this is the way to go:

```
def __enter__(self):
    self.start()
    return self
```

and

```
def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
    self.stop()
```

But I'm really not sure what I'm doing here. How should it be done properly?

Comment: What is your question exactly?  You seem to have a solution for what you're trying to do.

Comment: My solution is just some code I am trying. The question is how this should be done properly?

Comment: What is the point of this Sleeper class? What are you sleeping for, and why do you need a separate thread to do it?

Comment: Indeed that particular sleeper is pointless. The one I use has more code that is very specific to AWS SQS and I thought not relevant to the question. I use it along a worker that does some time consuming task and this thread makes sure the visibility timeout of the SQS message gets pushed back as the main worker keeps working. If the worker fails, then the `finally` stops the thread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even though not quite understand your question, due to lack of background of your aws related problem. It's doable to use context to do this, just as you mentioned.

```
import threading
import time


class Sleeper(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, sleep=5.0):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, name='Sleeper')
        self.stop_event = threading.Event()
        self.sleep = sleep

    def run(self):
        print('Thread {thread} started'.format(thread=threading.current_thread()))
        while self.sleep > 0 and not self.stop_event.is_set():
            time.sleep(1.0)
            self.sleep -= 1
        print('Thread {thread} ended'.format(thread=threading.current_thread()))

    def stop(self):
        self.stop_event.set()

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.stop()
        print('Force set Thread Sleeper stop_event')


with Sleeper(sleep=2.0) as sleeper:
    time.sleep(5)

print('Main Thread ends')
```

You can test the two cases: 1. main sleep more time, 2. Sleeper thread has a bigger sleep parameter, they will end up two results;

If you still want to interact with the Sleeper thread with the main, your code should looks like this:

```
with Sleeper(sleep=2.0) as sleeper:
    cnt = 15

    while cnt > 0 and sleeper.is_alive():
        print(cnt)
        cnt -= 1
        time.sleep(1)
```

And you can see the main just print a few number, due to the sleeper has end and is not alive anymore.